# "blame me on it"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, register

I have occasionally heard "blame me/them on it" and thought it was a bit jarring. The more common ways, I think, are "blame me/them for it" and "blame it on me/them."

Some examples:

> Alex said in a text message. “He’s probably going to blame me on it, but deep down, he knows he did it.” ([source](https://www.desmoinesregister.com/story/sports/college/iowa-state/randy-peterson/2019/08/25/iowa-state-cyclones-northern-iowa-allen-matt-campbell-big-12-chase-allen-college-football-panthers/2107704001/))
>
> I told you he was going to blame me on it. (American TV series *House of Cards*)

My question is about the register and correctness of this phrase.

Comment: “Blame it on me” is fine.  “Blame me on it” is not really a standard phrase. Are you sure about the accuracy of the quote from “house of cards”?

Comment: @whiskeychief As much as I am sure "blame it on me" is more common, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Perhaps the author of the dialog is trying to show the character is unable to use standard English?

Comment: Agree with @DrMoishePippik.  There are some characters that are “southern” and may have a different regional dialect, or this could be intentionally odd-sounding (for stylistic purposes).  Note that [Google ngrams has absolutely no data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blame+it+on+me%2C+blame+me+on+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) for the phrase “blame me on it”.  That is not infallible but it suggests directionally that there’s something unusual about it.

Comment: @whiskeychief I'd have put up a link to a clip, but I can't find that scene in the public domain. It comes out of Frank Underwood, so I think "Southern" is a possibility.